# Canvas works in HTML file, but not javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I just finished my first JavaScript book, "Head First HTML5", and I'm feeling quite dumb. If i put the script in the HTML file it works, but doesn't work in a separate JavaScript file.

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="canArt.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas> 
</body>
</head>
```

JS file:

```
window.onload = init();
function init() {  
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");  
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  

 ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";  
 ctx.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);  

 ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";  
 ctx.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50);  
}
```

please help.

Answer (score 3):

Your immediately executing the `init` function by including the parens and assigning the result of `init`, which is nothing, to the `onload` handler...

change:

```
window.onload = init();
```

to:

```
window.onload = init;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sFmNw/

Comment: In other words, saying `= init();` executes the init function immediately and assigns its return value to window.onload, while saying `= init;` assigns the function itself as the onload handler.